# c++ win32 where to draw a meter

Tags: c++, winapi, drawing, gdi

I need to draw a meter using simple rectangles in a win32 app using c++. What would be the best method to draw a meter in a window (it should be redrawn, every 10ms)? Should i draw it directly into the window (on message WM_PAINT) or use some other component and draw into that?

Comment: 10 ms updating is generally unrealistic. You can't meaningfully update faster than the screen is drawn, which is only 60 Hz with most modern monitors (10 ms would be 100 Hz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a timer and respond to the WM_TIMER message by invalidating the part of the window that contains the meter using InvalidateRect. This will automatically generate WM_PAINT messages, but will keep them from piling up if the program falls behind.

Comment: so the best way would be to draw it directly in the window? not in some other component?

Comment: @blejzz: You should draw into the window where you're processing `WM_PAINT`.  That doesn't have to be the top-level window, you can create a child window with its own "meter custom control" window procedure and make it reusable like Windows built-in controls.

Comment: @blejzz, I've done it both ways - directly in the window, and as a child window. Child window gives better separation of concerns, but other than that I can't say I have a preference.

Comment: @blejzz: in Win32, child windows are the basis for components. Unless you have an architecture in place that allow for specific components (such as windowsless ActiveX controls. But you would know it), a child window is a good starting point for your meter "component". A next step would be to make it an ActiveX control. But you should start by trying to do the drawing.